# Jquery trigger dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Code

```
$('#shipping-address select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');

$('#shipping-address select[name=zone_id]').html('<option value="'+address_arr[8]+'" selected="selected">'+address_arr[10]+'</option>');
```

result

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBl7a.png)

[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62b4t.png)

Question: I  using trigger to refresh the dropdown list, but when my result is **Terengganu** it will auto jump to first one which is **Johor**, after tirgger I ald try to selected the results.

Please advise :(

Comment: Please provide all relevant code, and even better make a working example of the problem for us to test

Comment: create fiddle please,

Comment: Plz provide detailed requirement for this use case.  That will help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this code and it works fine:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function ($) {    
  var var1 = 'Barojerd';

  $(document.body).on('change', '#shipping_country', function () {
                    
     if ($('#shipping_country').val() == 'IR')
      $("#zone_id").append('<option selected="selected">' + var1 + '</option>');
     else
      $("#zone_id").append('<option>' + var1 + '</option>');                    
  
    $(bCity).change();

   });//end change country------------------------------------------


  $(document.body).on('change', '#zone_id', function () {
   setTimeout(function(){$('body').trigger('update_checkout'); }, 250 );

   });//end change zone_id---------------------------------------------

 });
            

 </script>
```

**and To receive Dropِown text:**

```
var e = document.getElementById("shipping_country");
shipping_country_Text= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain why that helps.